# Can we split a Java String Backwards?

Tags: java, string

I have a string

```
Product Description ID1 ID2 QTY Rate1 Rate2
```

I want do break it as

```
Product Description|ID1|ID2|QTY|Rate1|Rate2
```

The only common delimiter I could see is space. But product description can be any number of words. So I don't know how many spaces it will have. But the spaces in rest of the string is fixed.

Currently I split it into array, get its length and concat appropriately. Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me, but could you show the code.

Comment: Exactly same as @Robert3452's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by "more directly", but I'm assuming that you want to avoid the concatenation step.

One way would be as follows:

1. make an initial pass using `Matcher.find(int)` to find the position of the "N - 5th" separator.  (This requires an `int[]` with 5 elements that you use as a sort of queue for the offsets determined using `find`.)
2. use `String.substring` to extract the strings before and after that separator
3. use `String.split` to split the 2nd substring to separate the last 5 fields.

If you kept the offsets and match lengths (from step #1) you could replace the `split` call in step #3 with a loop and `substring` calls.

---

(The reason you can't in general split "backwards" is that regexes cannot be matched backwards.  Or more precisely, if you did that you might end up splitting differently to when you did it "forwards".  This makes it non-trivial to avoid doing 2 passes.  Obviously in your specific case, the separator regex would be "one-or-more-whitespace" which would work in both directions ... if there was a capability to do that in the Matcher API.).

Answer (score 2):

Split it into an array as normal
You will end up with an array with n + 5 components where n is the number of words in the product description.

Then you know:

```
Rate2 = arr[len-1]
Rate1 = arr[len-2]
QTY = arr[len-3]
ID2 = arr[len-4]
ID3 = arr[len-5]
```

Then combine elements arr[0] to arr[len-6] adding a space in between them. This gives you your product description.

Alternatively you could use Collections.reverse() on the output array but both methods get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Using a StringBuilder, this is probably as compact as you can get. The good thing is you don't have to juggle a lot of indices around. In fact, you don't have to juggle any.

```
    String foo = "Product Description Test Potato ID1 ID2 QTY Rate1 Rate2    ";
    foo = foo.trim(); // get rid of any extra spaces, in case we have any, as a safety check

    //the code that does your work
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder(foo);
    // we have to add the pipe 5 times
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) { 
        bar.setCharAt(bar.lastIndexOf(" "), '|');
    }
    foo = bar.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Product Description ID1 ID2 QTY Rate1 Rate2
    // Product Description|ID1|ID2|QTY|Rate1|Rate2

    String actWord = "Product it a middle data Description ID1 ID2 QTY Rate1 Rate2";
    String outputWord = null;
    String[] arr = actWord.split(" ");

    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i] + "=" + (i < arr.length - 5));
        if (i < arr.length - 5) {
            buf.append(arr[i] + " ");

        } else
            buf.append("|" + arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("output - " + buf.toString().trim());
```

I hope this solves your req.

Answer (score -1):

Reverse, the string.

Parse/Split based on space.

Re-reverse all the words as you pull them out of the collection of parsed/split words.

Not super elegant, but it should work.